# How to free TFrame after closing

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

When we close a frame, it is not freed, it still remains in the memory and it is still assigned.

How to track OnClose event of TFrame, to be able to free the frame?

Comment: Why don't you simply call `Free`?

Comment: Thanks  David Heffernan ,where i called free, because on closing frame no event occurrence. Please tell me.

Comment: Call Free when you want to close the frame before the host form. Otherwise you don't need to do anything. What is your actual problem? Tell us about that.

Comment: There is a form with button like(get frame). On the form one panel, On the panel there is one frame. When I clicked button, frame is display and i click on the frame it exit from panel means breakout and close button will appear. After closing frame when goes to click on buttion, frame will not show bec its already created. At this situation whart will do. Please help.

Comment: That suggests to me that your own code is checking for an existing frame and not creating a new frame, and you are not clearing the condition that marks an existing frame when the frame is "closed". If so, then simply use the frame's destructor to clear the condition. If you still need help, then please show your actual code.

Comment: Sorry for not post source code. Actually When goes to close frame, Then frame's destructor is not calling. Why?

Answer (score 4):

`TFrame` has no `OnClose` event.  You have to implement and track that manually.  However, when you are ready to free the Frame object, you can do what `TForm.Release()` does - post a custom message to yourself and then free the object in the message handler.  For example:

```
type
  TMyFrame = class(TFrame)
  private
    procedure CMRelease(var Message: TMessage); message CM_RELEASE;
  public
    procedure Release;
  end;
```

```
procedure TMyFrame.CMRelease(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  Free;
end;

procedure TMyFrame.Release;
begin
  PostMessage(Handle, CM_RELEASE, 0, 0);
end;
```

Just call `Release()` when you need to free the Frame, and it will free itself at its earliest convenience.